# How to target specific elements after mouseenter event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have this JS:

```
$(".play").mouseenter(function() {

    $( ".glitch-img" ).mgGlitch({
        // set 'true' to stop the plugin
        destroy : false, 
        // set 'false' to stop glitching
        glitch: true, 
        // set 'false' to stop scaling
        scale: true, 
        // set 'false' to stop glitch blending
        blend : true, 
        // select blend mode type
        blendModeType : 'hue',
        // set min time for glitch 1 elem
        glitch1TimeMin : 200, 
        // set max time for glitch 1 elem
        glitch1TimeMax : 400,
        // set min time for glitch 2 elem
        glitch2TimeMin : 10, 
        // set max time for glitch 2 elem
        glitch2TimeMax : 100, 
    });

}).mouseleave(function() {

    $( ".glitch-img" ).mgGlitch({
        destroy : true, // set 'true' to stop the plugin
    });

});
```

And my HTML is like this:

```
<div>
    <figure>
        <div class="glitch-img" style="background-image: url('assets/images/image.jpg')"></div>
    </figure>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="play play1"></div>
</div>
```

I don't know how to make my mouseenter work just on the current `.play`-element without affecting all the other `.play`-elements.

Comment: Why not use `$('.play').hover(function(){****onOver****},function(){****onLeave****});`..... ...**Or** remove the `$( function() {` inside functions.

Comment: show your html!

Comment: refine your selector if your current selector is selecting other unwanted elements as well.

Comment: Thank you, I removed the $( function(). I have two different divs .play which it's an icon and .glitch-img which it's an image placed in a different container. So I need to select this div how I did. I also need to execute my function just on the current .play otherwise it will affect the others .play

Comment: That's a lot of questions, please, re edit the post and make it clear.

Comment: Let me know if the solution in my answer works for you. If this is the case I would give you some other hints as well. regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get you right you actually want to target the `.glitch-img`-element which you can target like showen below (I also refactorized your code):

```js
handleGlitch = function( oEvent )
{
  // build the right configuration based on mouseenter/mouseleave
  oGlitch = oEvent.handleObj.origType == 'mouseleave'
  ? { destroy       : true } // config for "mouseleave"
  : { destroy       : false, // config for "mouseenter"
      glitch        : true, 
      scale         : true, 
      blend         : true, 
      blendModeType : 'hue',
      glitch1TimeMin: 200, 
      glitch1TimeMax: 400,
      glitch2TimeMin: 10, 
      glitch2TimeMax: 100 };

  // lets first get the element that triggered the event which is "div.play"
  // oEvent.target is the dom element on which the mouseenter/mouseleave event was fired
  $Play = $( oEvent.target ); // you can now do eg: $Play.addClass('active')|$Play.removeClass('active')

  // so now we have to target the right "div.glitch-img"
  // and not every "div.glitch-img" like it was before
  $Play
    .parent()            // get parent element of "div.play"
    .prev()              // get the previous element of that parent
    .find('.glitch-img') // now find the element with class "glitch-img"
    .mgGlitch( oGlitch ) // and do your glitchi stuff
}

// attache event handlers
// event object will be passed as an argument to handleGlitch function
$(".play").mouseenter( handleGlitch ).mouseleave( handleGlitch );
```

```html
<div>
  <figure>
    <div class="glitch-img" style="background-image: url('assets/images/image.jpg')"></div>
  </figure>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="play play1"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <figure>
    <div class="glitch-img" style="background-image: url('assets/images/image.jpg')"></div>
  </figure>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="play play2"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Edit/Recommendation**

If you are able to I would strongly suggest to refactorize your markup. While my answer may helped you out with your current issue the

```
$( oEvent.target ).parent().prev().find('.glitch-img')
```

part will probably fail as soon as you just change an itty bitty on your current markup as it strongly relies on the structure of your markup which is a bad practice in general. So I would do something like:

```
<div>
  <figure><!-- note the add of the id "glitch-1" which correspondents to "play-1" -->
    <div id="glitch-1" class="glitch-img" style="background-image: url('assets/images/image.jpg')"></div>
  </figure>
</div>
<div><!-- note the add of the id "play-1" which correspondents to "glitch-1" -->
  <div id="play-1" class="play"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <figure><!-- note the add of the id "glitch-2" which correspondents to "play-2" -->
    <div id="glitch-2" class="glitch-img" style="background-image: url('assets/images/image.jpg')"></div>
  </figure>
</div>
<div><!-- note the add of the id "play-2" which correspondents to "glitch-2" -->
  <div id="play-2" class="play"></div>
</div>
```

Now the structure of your markup is independent from the relation of `#play-[nr]` to `#glitch-[nr]` as long as you keep the pattern.

```
handleGlitch = function( oEvent )
{
  // now you can target your elements much more reliable and also more efficiently
  // lets get the number out of our "div.play" elment by its id
  sId = oEvent.target.id                   // eg: "play-1", "play-2"
  sNr = sId.substr( 1 + sId.indexOf('-') ) // eg: "1", "2"

  // now its easy to target the glitch element with vanilla JS
  document.getElementById( 'glitch-' + sNr )
  // but while you want to do some jQuery-mgGlitch-stuff you can do so by
  $( '#glitch-' + sNr ).mgGlitch( oGlitch )
}

$(".play").mouseenter( handleGlitch ).mouseleave( handleGlitch );
```

Or with other words: **you can now change your markup as you like without touching the JavaScript part anymore** which is a very good thing. Isn't it?

Comment: It works perfectly! thank you so much, it also looks better your code!

Comment: Dear @ditoje, I'm glad to help you out! If my answer solved your problem you can mark it as "accepted answer". Please also have a look at the **Edit/Recommendation** part I added to my answer...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$(this)` to identify the the currently active `$(".play")` element. Like this:

```
$(".play").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css("background","black")  // or whatever you want to do with it
    $(".glitch-img").mgGlitch({
    ...
    });

$(".play").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css("background","white")  // or whatever you want to do with it
    $(".glitch-img").mgGlitch({
    ...
    });
```